# Digital Persona U.R.U 4500 Issue with ZKSoftware

Tags: c#, sdk, fingerprint

I am using digital persona URU 4500 with C# SDK. evrything is fine, Image received function is working properly.

But image capture event is not working with  ZKFinger SDK for C#

```
private void axZKFPEngX1_OnImageReceived(object sender, AxZKFPEngXControl.IZKFPEngXEvents_OnImageReceivedEvent e)
        {

}
```

Image received function is working properly but the below image capture function is not working.

```
private void axZKFPEngX1_OnCapture(object sender, AxZKFPEngXControl.IZKFPEngXEvents_OnCaptureEvent e)
{
                MessageBox.Show("ON Capture");
}
```

What i further need to do this, i heard i need **Biokey.lic** file. but after adding that to System32 its not working.

**The same code works fine with URU4000 Scanner.**

http://eu.zksoftware.com/product.do?id=156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using digital persona own SDK to enroll and to verify.

Here is the code to save template data to DB if anyone having issues.

```
switch (Enroller.TemplateStatus)
                    {
                        case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Ready:   // report success and stop capturing
                            OnTemplate(Enroller.Template);
                            MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
                            Enroller.Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
                            fingerprintData.Position = 0;
                            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
                            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);
                            Enroller.Template.Serialize(ref bytes);
                            string basestring = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                            string fingerprint_ = basestring;

                            Stop();
                            break;
}
```

Comment: Ronaldinho Learn Coding Hi, inbox on email and i will let you know step by step. Thanks.